# Extract zip and re-zip with password in java

Tags: java, zip4j

I am trying to extract list of zip files from folder and then re-zipping them with password. The problem is while re-zipping, the iteration/loop is not stopping. Also, re-zipped files should be a separate zip file each rather than merging all contents to one zip.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.util.Zip4jConstants;

public class AddFilesWithAESEncryption2 {

    public AddFilesWithAESEncryption2() {

        try {
            //Extract Zip files as folders
            try {
                String ZipSourcePath = "E:/EZipTest/";
                String ExtractTo = "D:/DZipTest/";
                String files1;
                File folder1 = new File(ZipSourcePath);
                File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles1[i].isFile()) {
                        files1 = listOfFiles1[i].getName();
                        String ZipFiles = "E:/EZipTest/" + files1;

                        try {
                            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ZipFiles);
                            List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();
                            zipFile.extractAll(ExtractTo);
                        } catch (ZipException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Get list of folders    
                String DirectoryNames;
                String ExtractedDirectories1 = "D:/DZipTest/";
                File folder2 = new File(ExtractedDirectories1);
                File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles2[i].isDirectory()) {
                        DirectoryNames = listOfFiles2[i].getName();
                        String ListOfDirectories = "D:/DZipTest/" + DirectoryNames;

                        //Get list of files
                        String ExtractedDirectories = ListOfDirectories;
                        File folder3 = new File(ExtractedDirectories);
                        File[] listOfFiles3 = folder3.listFiles();

                        for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles3.length; j++) {
                            File file = listOfFiles3[j];
                            if (file.isFile()) {
                                String FileNames = file.getName();
                                System.out.println(ListOfDirectories + FileNames);

                                //Compress and zip the files
                                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("D:/" + listOfFiles2[i].getName() + ".zip");
                                ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();
                                filesToAdd.add(new File(ListOfDirectories + FileNames));
                                ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
                                parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); // set compression method to deflate compression
                                parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
                                parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
                                parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
                                parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
                                parameters.setPassword("test");
                                zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ZipException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddFilesWithAESEncryption2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of unzipping *all* files and then zipping everything, unzip *one* file only, rezip it, delete the files and continue with the next zip file. Try to use Eclipse's `Refactor/Extract method` functionality and you'll get a nice and understandable code.

Comment: How do I go to next file after unzipping. Right now I am scan for files and folder and passing it in parameters to be zipped/unzipped. I will have a look eclipse as you said

Answer (score 4):

### Refactoring

Refactoring your code will help you understand what it does. It will reveal the problem and immediately identify a fix. Here's how it goes. Note that this is not a complete tutorial, but I hope you get the point.

First, extract a nice method that does the unzipping. Mark everything inside the first `for` loop, then right click and choose `Refactor / Extract Method...`. Name it `unzipFile`. Note that you now have a nice small, potentially reusable and potentially testable (JUnit) method.

Next, mark everything from `ZipParameters parameters` to `parameters.setPassword("test");` Right click, `Refactor / Extract Method...`. Name it `getEncryptionParameters`. Note how 7 lines of code have been removed from the long method and readability is improved.

Right click on `parameters` and choose `Refactor / Inline ...`. Note how the temporary variable disappears.

### See the bug

If you have followed closely, there is a piece of code like this:

```
//Compress and zip the files
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("D:/" + listOfFiles2[i].getName() + ".zip");
ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();
filesToAdd.add(new File(ListOfDirectories + FileNames));
zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, getEncryptionParameters());
```

See what it does? It creates a new ZIP file, adds only **one** file to `filesToAdd` and that's it. But why? It says `FileNames`. How can that be one file only?

Looking at

```
String FileNames = file.getName();
```

that's really just one file, so the variable name is wrong.

Right click `FileNames` and choose `Refactor/Rename...`. Enter `fileName`. Note how the variable name in your program matches to what it really is. It heavily improves readability of the code.

### Simplify

Now that you know you're adding only one file, use `addFile()` instead of `addFiles()`. You're getting rid of the `ArrayList`:

```
//Compress and zip the files
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("D:/" + listOfFiles2[i].getName() + ".zip");
File fileToAdd = new File(ListOfDirectories + fileName);
zipFile.addFile(fileToAdd, getEncryptionParameters());
```

### Fix the bug

As spotted before, a `new ZipFile(...)` is created inside the loop and only one file is added to it. Move that line out of the loop pressing <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd>.

### Continue refactoring

A part of the problem is already fixed (I haven't tried, actually), but your code is still not error-free. Let's go on:

Mark everything from `File[] listOfFiles3` to the end of the `for` loop that follows. Right click, `Refactor/Extract Method...`, name it `rezip`. Your big method becomes smaller again.

Right click on `ExtractedDirectories`, `Refactor / Inline ...`. You just got rid of a unnecessary temporary variable.

See something? Your code should look like this:

```
//Get list of files
File folder3 = new File(ListOfDirectories);
rezip(listOfFiles2, i, ListOfDirectories, folder3);
```

Note how `folder3` and `ListOfDirectories` is essentially the same. Let's get rid of it. Move the line `File folder3 = new File(ListOfDirectories);` into the method, just behind `private void rezip(...){` and remove the parameter `File folder3` from both, the method call and the method declaration of `rezip()`.

The loop using `rezip()` now looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles2[i].isDirectory()) {
        DirectoryNames = listOfFiles2[i].getName();
        String ListOfDirectories = "D:/DZipTest/" + DirectoryNames;
        rezip(listOfFiles2, i, ListOfDirectories);
    }
}
```

You might spot that `DirectoryNames` is actually just one, not many. Right click, `Refactor/Rename...`. Enter `subDirectory`.

Right click `subDirectory`, `Refactor / Inline ...`. Read the error message. Right click `References / Workspace`. Check the results and find out that this variable is only used within the `for` loop. Delete the declaration outside and declare it at its first use. Now do the `Refactor / Inline ...` operation.

Your code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles2[i].isDirectory()) {
        String ListOfDirectories = "D:/DZipTest/" + listOfFiles2[i].getName();
        rezip(listOfFiles2, i, ListOfDirectories);
    }
}
```

Again, there's a variable name indicating a list or an Array, but that's not true. `Refactor / Rename...`, name it `directoryToZip`.

Inline the following variables in this order: `ExtractedDirectories1`, `folder2`, `ZipSourcePath`, `folder1`.

Rename in this order `listOfFiles1` to `zipFiles` and `listOfFiles2` to `extractedDirectories`.

Remove `files1` since it is never used.

### The final bug

The method is now short and readable enough to understand it completely. Does the following make sense?

```
String ExtractTo = "D:/DZipTest/";
File[] zipFiles = new File("E:/EZipTest/").listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < zipFiles.length; i++) {
    unzipFile(ExtractTo, zipFiles, i);
}

File[] extractedDirectories = new File("D:/DZipTest/").listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < extractedDirectories.length; i++) {
    if (extractedDirectories[i].isDirectory()) {
        String directoryToZip = "D:/DZipTest/" + extractedDirectories[i].getName();
        rezip(extractedDirectories, i, directoryToZip);
    }
}
```

No it doesn't.

1. You don't want to extract all archives first but one by one
2. You don't want to zip subdirectories, you want to zip everything in the `ExtractTo` directory

### Fixing the final bug

The signature of `unzipFile()` does not look right. If it unzips one file only as the name suggests, why does it get access to all files then?

Replace `unzipFile(ExtractTo, zipFiles, i);` by `unzipFile(ExtractTo, zipFiles[i]);`. This breaks the code. Eclipse will mark it red. Fix it by changing the parameters from

```
private void unzipFile(String ExtractTo, File[] listOfFiles1, int i)
```

to

```
private void unzipFile(String ExtractTo, File listOfFiles1)
```

Inside `unzip`, replace `listOfFiles1[i]` by `listOfFiles1`. Then `Refactor/Rename...` it to `sourceZipFile`.

Similar for the `rezip` method: it should get the directory to zip and the target file name only. Therefore change

```
rezip(extractedDirectories, i, directoryToZip);
```

to

```
rezip(extractedDirectories[i], directoryToZip);
```

Then adapt the method itself from

```
private void rezip(File[] listOfFiles2, int i, String ListOfDirectories) throws ZipException
```

to

```
private void rezip(File listOfFiles2, String ListOfDirectories) throws ZipException
```

then change `listOfFiles2[i]` to `listOfFiles2`. Rename it to `targetFile`.

Now you have a nice `unzipFile()` method and a `rezip()` method. Let's combine it in a cool way:

```
String ExtractTo = "D:/DZipTest/";
File[] zipFiles = new File("E:/EZipTest/").listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < zipFiles.length; i++) {
    unzipFile(ExtractTo, zipFiles[i]);
    rezip(zipFiles[i], ExtractTo);
    // TODO: delete extracted files here
}
```

Awesome, ain't it?

### Notes

Maybe you've seen how much effort it is to understand your code and provide a fix. Actually, too much effort for Stack Overflow. Next time you ask a question, please try to provide code that is at minumum as readable as your code now.

The code is still not as clean as it should be. Spend some more time on it. When you think it's superb, post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get even more instructions.

Comment: I can see in the program its adding only one file as you said, but `String FileNames = file.getName();` is in a for loop and suppose to get all file names right?

Comment: Wow, super! Thanks so much Thomas. That's a lot of effort. No one has given a description like this till now. I can analyse the code now and I will in mind about readability next time ;)

Comment: Move the lineFile `folder3 = new File(ListOfDirectories);into the method` What should I name the method here?

Comment: Like this `rezip(listOfFiles2, i, ListOfDirectories,new File(ListOfDirectories));` ?

Comment: Sorry if that's not thoroughly described. Don't move it into the method call but inside the method declaration, the first line below `private void rezip(...){`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81545/discussion-between-kittu-and-thomas).

Comment: As spotted before, a new ZipFile is created inside the loop and only one file is added to it. `Move that line out of the loop pressing` Alt+Up. which line should I move out of loop? `zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters);`??

Comment: Can you see me in the chat? Move `ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(...)` out of the loop

Comment: I am doing this unzipping:`for (int i = 0; i < zipFiles.length; i++) 
                {
                        try {
                            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFiles[i]);
                            zipFile.extractAll(ExtractTo);
                        } catch (ZipException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }` So all this code should be refactored ?

Comment: If you do it like this, all ZIP files will be extracted first, resulting in a mixture of files. Delete that part.

Comment: I changed it and sent it in chat to you